# Saving a file without using the SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, file, save, wave

As the topic states: How can I save a wave file to a folder without using the `SaveFileDialog`?

I usually do it by `.SaveAs`. I can save using `SaveFileDialog` but is there a way to save to a specific folder in a directory like `@"~/test/" + filename ?` instead of using `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Show us what did you write in code ? And then tell where in that part you stuck ?

Comment: i've got no idea how to begin to save , i been googling , theres only SaveFileDialog which i am using atm and is working well but i dun want user to decide where to save , i want to save it into a folder just like the above .

Comment: i googled for 1 min and found the solution...

Answer (score 1):

you could for example convert it to a byte array (`bytes`) and then save it like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\yourFile.wav"))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```